# Accuracy of -newer test

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, timestamps, test

It appears that the`-newer` test is not quite as accurate as I would like.  Using `ls -lt` I get the correct sort order:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 p  staff      48 Jan 26 14:42 foo.gdb
-rw-r--r--@ 1 p  staff  328971 Jan 26 14:42 foo.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 p  staff    3133 Dec 14 05:52 foo.tex
```

But using the `-newer` test yields:

```
../isNewer.sh foo.gdb foo.pdf
File 1 is older than file 2

../isNewer.sh foo.pdf foo.gdb
File 1 is older than file 2
```

where `../isNewer.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -nt $2 ]; then
  echo "File 1 is newer than file 2"
else
  echo "File 1 is older than file 2"
fi
```

### Output of `stat`:

As requested in the comments, the output of `stat foo.pdf foo.gdb` (with manually added spaces for readabilty) is:

```
16777217 255313605 -rw-r--r-- 1 p staff 0 328971 "Jan 26 21:28:06 2017" "Jan 26 14:42:16 2017" "Jan 26 21:27:33 2017" "Jan 26 14:42:16 2017" 4096 648 0 foo.pdf
16777217 255313604 -rw-r--r-- 1 p staff 0 48     "Jan 26 21:27:33 2017" "Jan 26 14:42:16 2017" "Jan 26 21:27:33 2017" "Jan 26 14:42:16 2017" 4096 8   0 foo.gdb
```

### Questions:

- What is the accuracy of the the `-newer` test>?
- Is there an alternative that will do a more fine tuned test for one file being newer than another (one that can compare down to the second instead of the minute)?

### Platform:

- MacOS with bash 3.2.53(1)-release

Comment: Please add the output of `stat foo.gdb` and `stat foo.pdf`, I'm not convinced `ls` will not break ties (at the displayed accuracy) by filename.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Have added output of `stat`. Looks like `ls -lt` was sorting alphabetically. But, there still must be a way to compare file time stamps to more precision than a minute. A second of precision would be adequate for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-nt` operator will use the time of last modification when comparing the age of the two files.

According to your `stat` output, the two files in this example have the *exact same modification time* (down to the second), `Jan 26 14:42:16 2017` (the second timestamp in the `stat` output).

Therefore, one file is not "newer" than the other, and the test returns false no matter in which order the test is performed.

Comment: Ok, that explains the issue with my test case. Will look into that issue further, but can you elaborate on the what is the accuracy of the `-newer` test, and is there an alternative that can compare to a finer resolution?  Also, I had no idea that using a Dvorak keyboard meant you were not a nice person. :-) Must be some trumpism. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill The timestamps on files are stored with a resolution of one second. There is no finer resolution.

Comment: Ok, so the `-newer` will be able to differentiate down to the `second` then.

Comment: @PeterGrill Exactly, the `-nt` operator will use the `mtime` timestamp, and that is stored with a resolution of 1s.